# Using VSCode for CS50 getting an empty zip file so unable to unzip it

Tags: visual-studio-code, cs50

I am trying to complete the filter-less problem in CS50 week 4 but when I run the wget command I get the message:

```
#--2022-02-24 18:00:37--  https://cdn.cs50.net/2021/fall/psets/4/filter-more.zip
Resolving cdn.cs50.net (cdn.cs50.net)... 108.139.243.128, 108.139.243.21, 108.139.243.25, ...
Connecting to cdn.cs50.net (cdn.cs50.net)|108.139.243.128|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2159610 (2.1M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘filter-more.zip’

filter-more.zip                      0%[                                                              ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

Cannot write to ‘filter-more.zip’ (Success).
```

Then when I try to unzip filter-more.zip, I get the message:

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of filter-more.zip or
filter-more.zip.zip, and cannot find filter-more.zip.ZIP, period.

I have tried doing this with other wget commands and it still doesn't work. If I try to unzip the file on my PC, then save it to the VSCode workspace, I get an ENOSPC error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your directories that are no longer in use.
Most likely this is due to storage issues.